# Простейший unit-тест с grunt-contrib-qunit

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты

Объясните пожалуйста, как должен выглядеть простейший unit-тест для javaScript с использованием инструмента grunt-contrib-qunit?

[Тестовый проект на github](https://github.com/egorov-g-a/grunt-contrib-qunit-test.git)

Не пойму почему PhantomJS не понимает что такое qunit. В package.json все зависимости прописаны и npm install их все скачивает.

Признаю, нет великого опыта javascript, nodejs, grunt, phantomjs.

C Getting Started на qunitjs.com разобрался, с этим проблем нет. Тест проходит.
Но хочется видеть в консоли, что тесты прошли. Понятно, что есть и другие инстументы для тестирования javascript-кода, но после 2-х дней битья головой об стену, хочется понять, что же я делаю не так, и как заставить работать grunt-contrib-qunit.

В папке test лежит файл index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>QUnit Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.20.0.css"> </head>
<body>
<div id="qunit"></div>
<div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.20.0.js"></script>
<script src="tests.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

В Gruntfile.js таск для qunit настроен на обработку всех файлов с расштрением html

```
qunit: {
      files: ['test/**/*.html']
},
```

Сам тест, файл tests.js

```js
QUnit.test( "hello test", function( assert ) {
  assert.ok( 1 == "1", "Passed!" );
});
```

На фазе тестирования все валится

[image: grunt default task]

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решилась.

Просто скачал файлы библиотеки qunit.js и qunit.css и подложил их в проект. Соответственно и ссылки в test/index.html поменял, указав локальные копии файлов библиотеки.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>QUnit Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../qunit/qunit-1.20.0.css">
  <script src="../qunit/qunit-1.20.0.js"></script>
  <script src="tests.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Теперь тесты проходят]